# Can I shorten a length of C9 Christmas lights?

Tags: led, wiring, light

I have a string of 25 C9 LED Christmas lights, and I'd like to shorten the string.  After untangling the string, they seem to be wired like this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRT5cu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've removed a few of the lights between D4 and D23, but when I plug the string in D2 explodes. Is it possible to shorten the string of lights?  Do I have to add a resistor if I remove too many lights? If so, how do I know what size resistor to put in the circuit?

Comment: Wow... 10,000 views on a closed question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each LED has a specific forward voltage drop (it depends on color and power etc) if you remove some from the middle of a series, the overall voltage drop will be less. This means that you need to reduce the voltage applied to the diminished series.

You don't show what is powering these LEDs. It is possible to use a constant-current circuit that would avoid this sort of problem.

If you know (or can measure) the LED current for each LED (end therefore for a series) and the voltage drop of each and the applied voltage, you could calculate the resistance and wattage of a resistor to limit the current to  a safe value.

$$ R = { V_{supply} - n  V_{LED} \over I_{LED} } $$

$$ P = {I_{LED}}^2 R $$

Answer (score 2):

Inexpensive strings of lights probably aren't going to have particularly elaborate ways of controlling the power that goes to each LED, and are probably not going to be especially robust in case anything goes wrong with one or more of the LEDs.  Any strings sold by reputable retailers will probably be designed not to catch fire under any realistic failure scenarios that do not involve tampering, but beyond that all bets are off.

If you can isolate moderate-length simple series strings of LEDs, I would suggest that your best bet would be to drive them with a current-controlled boost-mode switching power supply circuit designed for LEDs.  Do not try to drive anything directly from the AC mains.  Instead, use a safety-certified power supply to convert the mains voltage to something probably in the 3V-12V range and then use a booster circuit which can produce enough voltage to drive the LEDs.  Although it would *probably* be possible to make a simpler and cheaper circuit that would work "directly" off the mains, it would *certainly* be possible to cause severe harm to persons or property in the attempt, so unless you're designing for mass production and can afford a lot of safety engineering I really wouldn't recommend such an approach.